# execute multiple select statements using sqlite library

Tags: sqlite

I am developing a Iphone App.
I need to know whether we can execute multiple insert statements in a batch at once using sqlite3 database.
As we do this in Core java in JDBC bt using execute_batch can we do the same using sqlite3 database?Can any one guide me how can i do this using sqlite3 by providing any code or link?

Thanks,
Shradha

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by performing next queries:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ....;
INSERT ....;
INSERT ....;
INSERT ....;
COMMIT;
```

Be careful with TCL, sqlite3 won't perform any DML and DDL till transaction will be **COMMIT**.

With using statements you won't be able to perform few commands at once if they separated by ';', statement prepare have pointer at which it will place commands which won't be performed int this statement.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass multiple statements separated by a semicolon.
Example: "delete from table1;delete from table2;" This will delete the contents of table1 and table2. Similarly we can create insert statements.